# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract! java.util.Date

Tags: java, sorting, date, timsort

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeLo(TimSort.java:747)
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:483)
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse(TimSort.java:410)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:214)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:173)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:659)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:217)
```

I am sorting a collection based on the following comparator.

```
public static Comparator<MyClass> CMP_TIME_DESC = new Comparator<MyClass>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(MyClass o1, MyClass o2) {
        return o2.getOrderSendTime().compareTo(o1.getOrderSendTime());
    }
};
```

The values are always non-null.
And the getOrderSendTime() object is of the java.util.Date class.

I understand that this is a transitivity inconsistency, and I would assume a class like this would not have such issues. I searched for open issues, but did not find any on the topic.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that there isn't some other thread (or simply some computation in `getOrderSendTime()` with side effects) that modifies the dates while the sort is in progress?

Comment: Yes, the objects are obtained by querying the database, and they have a local scope.
In addition there is no computation going on.

Comment: If I use thousands of random generated dates, I obain no errors. Can you provide us a [a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I have been unable to reproduce it reliably and as far as I'm aware it happened only 2-3 times. 
I have not attempted to collect data since at that point it only happened on a productive environment. 
So unfortunately I cannot provide a true MCV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this same exception, and it happened when I had `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Timestamp` objects in the same list/array when being sorted, running on Java8.  (This mix was due to some objects being loaded from database records with the `Timestamp` data type, and others being created manually, and the objects having only a `Date` object in them.)

The exception also doesn't happen every time you sort the same data set, and it seems that there also have to be at least 32 of these mixed objects in the array for it to occur.

If I use the legacy sort algorithm, this also doesn't occur (see how in Ortomala Lokni's answer).

This also doesn't happen if you use only `java.util.Date` objects or only `java.sql.Timestamp` objects in the array.

So, the issue seems to be `TimSort` combined with the compareTo methods in `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Timestamp`.

**However, it didn't pay for me to research why this is happening since it is fixed in Java 9!**

As a workaround until Java9 is released and we can get our systems updated, we have manually implemented a `Comparator` that only uses `getTime()`.  This seems to work fine.

Here is code that can be used to reproduce the issue:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TimSortDateAndTimestampTest {

    // the same test data with all Dates, all Timestamps, all Strings or all Longs does NOT fail.
    // only fails with mixed Timestamp and Date objects
    @Test
    public void testSortWithTimestampsAndDatesFails() throws Exception {
        List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<>();
        dates.add(new Timestamp(1498621254602L));
        dates.add(new Timestamp(1498621254603L));
        dates.add(new Timestamp(1498621254603L));
        dates.add(new Timestamp(1498621254604L));
        dates.add(new Timestamp(1498621254604L));
        dates.add(new Timestamp(1498621254605L));
        dates.add(new Timestamp(1498621254605L));
        dates.add(new Timestamp(1498621254605L));
        dates.add(new Timestamp(1498621254605L));
        dates.add(new Timestamp(1498621254606L));
        dates.add(new Timestamp(1498621254607L));
        dates.add(new Date(1498621254605L));
        dates.add(new Timestamp(1498621254607L));
        dates.add(new Timestamp(1498621254609L));
        dates.add(new Date(1498621254603L));
        dates.add(new Date(1498621254604L));
        dates.add(new Date(1498621254605L));
        dates.add(new Date(1498621254605L));
        dates.add(new Date(1498621254607L));
        dates.add(new Timestamp(1498621254607L));
        dates.add(new Date(1498621254608L));
        dates.add(new Timestamp(1498621254608L));
        dates.add(new Date(1498621254611L));
        dates.add(new Timestamp(1498621254612L));
        dates.add(new Timestamp(1498621254613L));
        dates.add(new Date(1498621254607L));
        dates.add(new Timestamp(1498621254607L));
        dates.add(new Timestamp(1498621254608L));
        dates.add(new Timestamp(1498621254609L));
        dates.add(new Timestamp(1498621254611L));
        dates.add(new Date(1498621254603L));
        dates.add(new Date(1498621254606L));

        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            Collections.shuffle(dates);
            Collections.sort(dates);
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** I have removed the exception expectation so you can SEE it throwing when run.

Comment: Still occurs randomly in openjdk11.0.4 onboard... However im using streams API and custom comparator. Sometimes happens, sometimes not...

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is related to this one: [Sort algorithm changes in Java 7](http://dertompson.com/2012/11/23/sort-algorithm-changes-in-java-7/)

It happens because the default sort algorithm has [changed from MergeSort to TimSort](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6804124).

One workaround is to add `-Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true` to the JVM environment.

The best option is to conform to the comparison general contract but I think you didn't provide enough information in your question for this.

Comment: I am aware of the algorithm change, basically merge sort would not 'scream' if the collection was not sorted successfully. 

But there's an obvious problem with either the data or the comparator and the sorting was done with the above given comparator on the java.util.Date class.

If there's no known issue with this it might just mean that the data was corrupted and killed the sorting.

Comment: So you should add the minimal set of data triggering this error to the question.

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to do so. 
This was a problem that got reported to me, and I did not manage to reproduce it myself.
And for various I was unable to obtain the/any data that triggers the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Faced this problem today, after spending a few hours, realized that I was comparing Longs. Instead, you need to compare Long.longValue().

MyData.utcTime() returns Long. So instead of:

```
public static Comparator<MyData> sortByUtcPublishedDesc = new Comparator<MyData>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(MyData n1, MyData n2) {
        if ( n2.utcTime() < n1.utcTime() )
            return -1;
        if ( n2.utcTime() == n1.utcTime() )
            return 0;
        // if (n2.utcTime() > n1.utcTime())
        return 1;
    }
};
```

I used, the following to fix the problem.

```
public static Comparator<MyData> sortByUtcPublishedDesc = new Comparator<MyData>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(MyData n1, MyData n2) {
        if ( n2.utcTime().longValue() < n1.utcTime().longValue() )
            return -1;
        if ( n2.utcTime().longValue() == n1.utcTime().longValue() )
            return 0;
        // if (n2.utcTime() > n1.utcTime())
        return 1;
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Add "-Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true" to the VM argument.

Comment: That just hides the problem, does not resolve it. 
Using that flag can lead to a buggy behavior where the sorting is wrong.